# jquery AJAX delete script from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete the files from the database by AJAX call. but I think I am missing something to do so..I am getting only * del".$row1['id']." * instead of del id ... Please help me over it .

// My main file//

```
<html>
<body>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<h3><p align="center"><u>Filer ladda upp och ned</u></p></h3>
<div class="table-responsive">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" name="form" method="post">
 <table id="files" border="1" align="center" id="table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td align="center">DOWNLOAD</td></tr>
<?php
$select=mysql_query("select * from upload order by id desc");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
    $name=$row1['name'];
?>
<tr>
<td width="300">
<img src="files/tick.png" width="14" height="14"><p><?php echo $name ;?></p>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<a data-value=".$row1['id']." id=del".$row1['id'].">Delete</a>
</td>
<?php }?>
</tr>

</table>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(".del<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>").click(function() {
      if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")) {
        var delcart = $(this).data('value');
        //alert(delcart);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "del_file.php",
            data: {id : delcart},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    //alert('data');
                    window.location.reload();
                    }
                    }
                    });
      }
      //alert($(this).data('value'));
      });
   </script>



</form>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />


</body>
</html>
```

//My del_file.php //

```
<?php
$del_id = $_GET['id'];
echo $del_id;
include'config.php' ;
$delete_item = mysql_query("delete from upload where id = $del_id ");
if($delete_item){
    echo '1';
}else{
    echo '0';
}
?>
```

Thank you .

Comment: have you debug your code, that $del_id to delete query is getting or not ?

Comment: Do you get proper id in `alert(delcart);`

Comment: @Anandjain no its not working.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit no in console only del".$row1['id']." this shows.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: `<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` should go in the `<head><script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>` And you dont need it TWICE

Comment: @tanmoysarkar you are missing `echo $row1['id']` in your delete anchor tag

Comment: @RiggsFolly yaaa i should learn pdo  asap .thank you

Comment: @tanmoysarkar check my answer below.

Comment: @ArshSingh  
thank you i got my error as well as my answer . this my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the things in wrong way. `$row1['id']` without `<?php ?>` it turn to be out only a string which is `$row1['id']` and not an id from the loop. and another thing is your javascript selector is completely invalid , as it is outside of loop and it's not going to work at all. so better you follow the following code and make it possible in a better way.

Note again:

Your `$row1['id']` is outside of while loop , so `$row1['id']` is totally invalid and does not mean anything.

As you are targeting multiple files from the same page (let take an example that there are multiple elements and trigger for removing files connecting to same javascript function) You can use `class selectors` to get click event of multiple elements with same scope.

replace your delete anchor tag with :

```
<a data-value="<?= $row1['id'];?>" class="remove_file">Delete</a>
```

and then your javascript code should be like :

```
$(".remove_file").click(function() {
 var delcart = $(this).data('value');
      if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "del_file.php",
            data: {id : delcart},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    //alert('data');
                    window.location.reload();
                    }
                    }
                    });
      }
      //alert($(this).data('value'));
      });
```

Comment: thank you i got my error as well as my answer . this my day .

Comment: @tanmoysarkar glad it did help you out :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(".del<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>").click(function() {
      if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")) {
        var delcart = $(this).data('value');
        var data = JSON.stringify({id : delcart});
        //alert(delcart);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "del_file.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    //alert('data');
                    window.location.reload();
                    }
                    }
                    });
      }
      //alert($(this).data('value'));
      });
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this?

Comment: This is not going to work as the javascript code is outside of while loop and `$row1['id']` does not even exist.